# как сделать чтоб текст исчез и появились кнопки

Tags: css3, html5, hover

[image: descr]

```css
.shoes1 .option-list {
  display: none;
  margin-top: -350px;
}

.shoes1:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="shoes">
  <div class="shoes1">
    <div class="price-box">$145,99</div>
    <div class="description">
      Even&Odd
      <div class="option-list">
        <button class="view"></button>
        <button class="wishes"></button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Уже все перепробывал, хочу сделать чтобы при наведении на блок shoes1 текст description исчезал и появлялся на его месте option-list с кнопками.
возможно структуру html нужно переделать?

Comment: без js хотите?)

Comment: можно и с js, я делеас с js, текст even&odd просто мигал при наведении, а кнопки не появлялись. устанавливал свойство display none при onmouseover и display: block при onmouseout

Comment: .shoes1:hover .option-list{display: block}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

или вот такой css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.shoes {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: silver;
}

.description,
.price-box {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.option-list {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

.shoes:hover .option-list {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.shoes:hover .description,
.price-box {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.shoes {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: silver;
}

.description,
.price-box {
  display: block;
}

.option-list {
  display: none;
}

.shoes:hover .option-list {
  display: block;
}

.shoes:hover .description,
.price-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\test\style\main.css">
  <script src="D:\test\js\adaptiveMenu.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="testwrap">
    <div class="test">
      <div class="shoes">
        <div class="shoes1">
          <div class="price-box">$145,99</div>
          <div class="description">Even&Odd</div>
          <div class="option-list">
            <button class="view">A</button>
            <button class="wishes">B</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: у меня текст мигает, но не исчезает, ладно будем фиксить) спасибо за ответ